# How to clean Plots (GR) without closing Julia environment

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I'm debugging a script (which use `Plots.jl` with `GKS QtTerm` backend). So I run the script many times. When I run it from terminal like `bash> julia pointPlacement.jl` it takes for ages to initialize Julia and Plots.jl (this is one big inconvenience in comparison to python). Therefore I rather keep Julia open and run the script from within, like `julia> include( "pointPlacement.jl" )`

```
grid = [ [ix*0.01 iy*0.01] for ix=1:100, iy=1:100 ]
grid = vcat(ps...)

centers = hexGrid( 2, 0.2 )

using Plots
display(scatter!( grid[:,1], grid[:,2], markersize = 1, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal ))
display(scatter!( centers[:,1], centers[:,2], markersize = 2, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal ))
```

The problem is that the plots accumulate. This is after 9 runs. There should be just 2 datasets, not 18:

[image]

I want to close (kill,destroy) them

If I remove `!` like this, it helps

```
display(scatter( grid[:,1], grid[:,2], markersize = 1, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal ))
display(scatter!( centers[:,1], centers[:,2], markersize = 2, markerstrokewidth = 0, aspect_ratio=:equal ))
```

but still, I worry that some junk (previous figures) stay allocated in memory and Julia will crash after I run the script 100x. Therefore I would like to call some function like `clear()`,`flush()`,`closeAll()` ... or something ... everytime I run the script

Comment: BTW, I think those `display` calls are unnecessary, aren't they?

Comment: yes they are ... just I saw them in some tutorial so I was trying if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing the `!` has the effect that you want - the plot is gone if you call `scatter` again and it doesn't live somewhere in the background.

If you want you can store the plot in a variable and overwrite it "to be safe", i.e.

```
p = scatter(...)
scatter!(p, ...)
```

, where `...` are your plotting arguments. This will explicitly overwrite `p` on every `include`.

Comment: The reason why I'm suspicious memory is not cleaned is that GR sometimes crash with error message like `to many files open`  (or `to many instances open`) and than `broken pipe` (I cannot reproduce it now and I don't remember exact message). So I was thinking it is related.

Comment: But this could have other reason - I have two instances of Julia running (one in bash-terminal inside `vscode` and other in separate bash-terminal where I try simple sniples). And both are using Pyplot with GR, and I see there is cross-talk (because when it crash the error appears in the other terminal then the one where I call the last plot function)

Answer (score 3):

This is a long comment on crstnbr's excellent answer. If you want to make a new plot, but it shares similarities with the previous one, you can define a "canvas" (for want of a better word) in a function, which I have named `new_plot()`, and reuse the canvas. This is particularly useful if you have long labels and titles that you do not want to keep copying from plot to plot:

```
using Plots

function new_plot()
    plot(xlabel = "x", ylabel = "f(x)",
        xlims = (0,Inf), ylims = (-Inf, 1))
end 

p = new_plot()
plot!(p, x -> x^2, 0, 1)
plot!(p, x -> x^3, 0, 1)
```

[image]

```
p = new_plot()
plot!(p, x -> 2^x, 0, 1)
plot!(p, x -> 3^x, 0, 1)
```

[image]

**Edit:** Not directly related to the OP anymore, but note that, as pointed out by Benoît Pasquier in a comment, you can set default options with:

```
default(xlabel = "x", ylabel = "f(x)", 
        xlims = (0,:auto), ylims = (:auto, 1))
```

but you'll still need to create a new plot to "overwrite" the previous one, as explained by crstnbr. Consider this:

```
using Plots
p = plot()
for i in 1:5
    plot!(p, x -> x^i, 0, 1)
end
```

Nothing happened? Now try this:

```
p  # after a loop, you must call the plot object to display it
```

Comment: What about, instead, using a `NamedTuple` for these keyword arguments? E.g., first create `options = (xlabel = "x", ylabel = "f(x)", xlims = (0,Inf), ylims = (-Inf, 1))` and then you can simply use `p = plot(x -> x^2, 0, 1; options...)`.

Comment: There's also `default(xlabel = "x", ylabel = "f(x)", xlims = (0,:auto), ylims = (:auto, 1))` if you *always* use the same default attributes, and then no need to even type anything! :)

Comment: Ah sorry I changed those `Inf` to `:auto` for my local tests, but `:auto` should work I think.  What version of Plots.jl are you on? (I'm on v1.13.2, GR_jll v0.57.2+0)

Comment: You probably have anotehr package that is holding back a dependency. You can try to `pkg> add Plots@v1.13.2` and investigate what's preventing the update. What I do is make sure my default environment is minimal and only has things I use all the time (Plots is one of them) and then always `pkg> activate --temp` to start a fresh environement for any MWE.

Comment: Hi Benoit! Thanks. You're right I had a package that was holding ``Plots`` back. It wasn't easy to diagnose. I deleted my ``.julia`` directory and reinstalled my packages and I was still stuck with the old version! Fortunately running ``Pkg.pkg"add Plots#master"`` helped me to identify the package that was messing things up. Thanks for your help! And now ``:auto`` works. Cool trick!

Answer (score 1):

I found setting `Plots.CURRENT_PLOT.nullableplot = nothing` to be the easiest way to clear  the current plot.